# Loop through a list both as a variable and as a string

Tags: bash

I have a long text file from which I want to grep all the lines that are with a given id (`id123`), and save them in a new text file.

In order to to this I can just execute the command:

```
zgrep -Hx id123 *.vcf.gz > /home/Roy/id123.txt
```

However, I have not one, but actually 20 files, so I would need to write this command 20 times.
These files are big and they take a long time to be processed, so I would prefer have it running in the background.

That's why I would like to create a script that iterates through a list of the ids, specifying it in the command

For example purposes, something like:

```
list=("id123" "id124" "id125" "id126")

for i in "${list[@]}"
do
   zgrep -Hx $i *.vcf.gz > /home/Roy/$i.txt
done
```

Comment: `zgrep -x id123` doesn't select the lines that **start** with `id123` but the lines that **ARE** `id123`. Also, do you need the filenames in the output?

Comment: Thanks for the answers @kladderradatsch, why that command and not the one that I have? What is the improvement?

Comment: Thanks @fravadona, that's a typo in the question. Indeed I want the lines that are `id123`. And yes, it would be helpful to have the names in the output to be able to trace them

Comment: Oh! I see @kladderradatsch. If I run it on the path I shouldn't need to specify it right? Something like `$> -name <FILE_PATTERN> -exec zgrep -Hx id123 {} + > /home/Roy/id123.txt` would do?

Comment: @RoyBatty sorry, there was a misunderstanding from my side - have deleted my comments.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `awk` for dispatching the output of `zgrep`?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ids=(id123 id124 id125 id126)

zgrep -Hxf <(printf '%s\n' "${ids[@]}") *.vcf.gz |
awk -F ':' '{print > ("/home/Roy/" $NF ".txt")}'
```

Comment: I guess from your comment that my original script wouldn't dispatch the output to the correct files? Is there a way of doing it without AWK?

Comment: @RoyBatty Your code works but you decompress the files one time per search so it takes twice the time for searching two ids. `zgrep -f | awk` decompresses the files only once for whatever number of ids that you search; it'll be incomparably faster. I don't think that you can do it with an other "standard" tool than `awk`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh -x

find . | sed -n '/id[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt/' > stack

cat > ed1 <<EOF
1p
q
EOF

cat > ed2 <<EOF
1d
wq
EOF

next () {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
exit 0
}

main () {
line=$(ed -s stack < ed1)
zgrep -Hx "${line}" *.vcf.gz > /home/Roy/"${line}".txt
ed -s stack < ed2
next
}

next
```